# WSUS Export Error: The gzip stream cannot contain more than 4GB data

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, wsus-offline

WSUS-SrvA is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and can sync updates.

WSUS-SrvB is running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and is on a detached network.

When we run `wsusutil.exe export export.xml.gz logfile` we receive the error: `Fatal Error: The gzip stream cannot contain more than 4GB data`

From my investigations on via Google, I found that .NET 2 had this issue and the issue was resolved in .NET 4.

We have installed .NET 4 on the server and I have changed the Application Pool for WSUS site in IIS, but I still receive the above error.

Do I need to do something else to switch WSUS to use .NET 4? Or is this something else?

I have installed the update for this as per http://blogs.technet.com/b/wsus/archive/2013/04/09/problem-solved-the-wsus-export-bug.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further digging, I found that we needed to run wsusutil.exe with .NET4 and the way to do this was as follows:

1. Create a file named `wsusutil.exe.config` in `C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools`
2. Edit the file and add the following:

   `<configuration><startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" /></startup></configuration>`
3. Re-run the `wsusutil` command and all should be well

I couldn't get the XML to appear correctly, so had to place it all on one line.

Neil

Answer (score 0):

Neil,
Thank you for posting this information because it is really helpful.  If I may add my 2 cents.

In order to verify that you have .Net Framework version 4.0.30319 go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
OR
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\

Search for clr.dll and right click on it then go to Details to find what version or .Net Framework.

Comment: Since the OP was asking about _how_ to get WSUS using .NET 4, not checking which .NET version is used, your suggestions might be better placed as a comment, rather than as a solution to the original question.